# How to change the default port 9000 in Play 2.3.x in build definition?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

With Play 2.2.x I could set the default port with build.sbt file i.e:

Build.sbt

```
  play.Project.playScalaSettings

  play.Project.playDefaultPort := 9001
```

After 2.3.x upgrade `play.Project.playDefaultPort` does not exists any more.

I do not want to type`-Dhttp.port=9001` or `run 9001`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
play.PlayImport.PlayKeys.playDefaultPort := 9001
```

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.4/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayImport.scala#L111