# How to change the default port in the play project

Tags: playframework, sbt

As we know ,we can change the default port use this way

[How to change the default port 9000 in Play 2.3.x in build definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040275/how-to-change-the-default-port-9000-in-play-2-3-x-in-build-definition)

but it can not work in this condition:
we can use the cammand :

> sbt debian:packageBin

after this we get a ***.deb** file which could execute as a service in the Ubuntu.
My question is ,in this way ,why the service's default port is not I set before,
It becomes the play framework default port 9000? and how could I change its port?

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: After installing the debian package there should be a file located at `/etc/default/application_name` where the command args configured. Add  `-Dhttp.port=1234` where 1234 is the port you want to change to.